# How to use the specification to map a related entity attribute

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create a specification in my app, but one of these methods i did made throw this error : `Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name`

The method that throw this error is this one:
[image]

Basicaly i want to filter the adresses of this Entity:
[image]

using a specification, where did i do wrong?

Comment: addresses are many!! (and `Customer` doesn't "own" this relationship... try it on the Address(, which knows its customer);)

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I used a `javax.persistence.criteria.Join` interface to join the relationship and it works!

[image]